# Why axis ax.spines is not showing axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code I want to plot 4 quadrants. I want to make origin at 0. Since all these values are positive they should only appear in first quadrant. But I'm not getting the required result. I want to plot 500 values which also have some negative values. I only showed a part of data. How can I get theses values confined only to first quadrant.

```
`#data
[[0.20077017, 0.26503062]
[0.23604931, 0.23830369]
[0.3413382 , 0.1511064 ]
[0.49108654 ,0.03759334]
[0.4908852,  0.03612228]
[0.48980197 ,0.03400265]
[0.49243385, 0.03560147]
[0.492753 ,  0.03494545]
[0.49211517, 0.03319726]
[0.4918935 , 0.03200188]
[0.4953385 , 0.03440943]
[0.49811  ,  0.03617451]])

c1 = data[:,0]
c2 = data[:,1]


ax.scatter(c1,c2)

ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_position('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_position('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')`
```

Comment: Does manually set xlim and ylim help ?

Comment: Yes after setting xlim and ylim from -0.5 to 0.5 it shows 4 quadrants. But the values in my data are too smaller than 0.5. How should I select the appropriate range of limits